# Can't use undeclared variable as shown in documentation due to unclear syntax

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

In [this article on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/cli-connect-to-sql#run-the-script), at the bottom of the section, there's a passage like this.

```
connstring=$(az sql db show-connection-string --name sqldb-info --server sql-server-v12 --client ado.net --output tsv)
connstring=${connstring//<username>/it_is_me}
```

Nowhere in the article I can see declaration of it (i.e. `$connstring`), which confuses me, as the sample doesn't work without it on my computer. I can try to correct it by declaring it. However, the second like does (as far I can tell) nothing.

I'm too ignorant of PS to figure out what that syntax is supposed to mean (checking the docs didn't really enlightened me). Somehow, I sense that nothing changes due to the second like for the same reason as the faulty declaration doesn't work. By other words, I'm considering that MS didn't make a mistake and I'm not actually fixing any problems by predeclaring the variable.

Where can I find more information on that specific syntax?

Comment: I’m pretty sure samples on that page are designed for the bash shell rather than Powershell - see the bit further up the page that says “Prerequisites: Use the Bash environment in Azure Cloud Shell.” and “When Cloud Shell opens, verify that Bash is selected for your environment.”

Comment: To emphasize @mclayton comment, if it did concern PowerShell, I would recommend to use [Azure cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az) as [az.sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/az.sql/) instead.

Comment: @iRon I realize that the tag for PowerShell may be misleading, then. I want to use Azure CLI to make sure that I can work efficiently even in case the system I'll be put to doesn't have PS capacity for some reason. (Nothing I see in the cards at the moment but one never knows what's behind the corner.) PowerShell just happens to be the UI I used. The abilities of Bash and PS are so similar today so one doesn't notice those small discrepancies (almost) ever. Good suggestion, though.

Comment: @mclayton I second the suggestion above that your comment is excellent enough to be upgraded to an answer to be accepted. Then, we have the issue of what the syntax on the second line in the sample does but I sense it's simple string replacement and that such a feature is more then well-documented once one looks for Bash specific docs.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - although it might identify the root cause, i’m not sure my comment really *solves* the OP’s problem :-). Happy for someone else to post it though if they think it’s worth being promoted to an answer…

Answer (score 0):

NB. I dislike answering my own questions. However, @mclayton is too humble to do so themself, so I'll have to.

It turns out that the script linked to is for Bash, not PowerShell. Although most of it is applicable due to similar syntax, this particular sample wasn't. It says in the article: *Prerequisites: Use the Bash environment in Azure Cloud Shell*.

The resolution is either:

1. switch to Bash and use the sample verbatim, or
2. rewrite it a bit migrating to PowerShell.